# Android studio, Why does a button not stay in place

Tags: android, button

I am currently working on a new app in Android studio.  I added a button, but when you try to run the program on a virtual device the button goes to the top left of the screen, like it's not anchored in place.  It won't stay where I have put it, saying that this won't work either for a text box.  I haven't written any code for the button yet but when I see other people do this they don't need to write code when it will still work.  So I don't know whats going on.  Also I'm kinda a beginner at android studio but still have a good rough idea.

I am also using a macbook pro (Apple operating system).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the **alignment properties** for the Components (Button,TextView,EditText etc..)based on the Layout(Linear ,Relative,Constraint) You are using.
Try these

- android:layout_gravity="center"
- android:gravity="center"

Know more about [Layouts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) , [Alignment in Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Layout.Alignment.html) and [Codelabs Example](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0)

Comment: Thank you so much i will try these suggestions out.

Comment: You are Welcome, Buddy..!! Happy Androidify..!! @Adam

Answer (score 1):

Yes thank you.
The final resolution is to put in the java area

app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomof="parent"

app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftof="parent"

app:layout_constraintRight_toRightof="parent"

app:layout_constraintTop_toLeftof="parent"

Just in case if anyone is looking for a resolved answer in android studio. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a TextView I was trying to add. There was a little magnet on the upper left corner I had to click to fix the issue on the Design window.